# How to pass authentication token in chromium

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, chromium

I am spawning chromium-browser in kiosk mode

```
    optionsArray.push("--app="+url);
    spawn("chromium-browser", optionsArray);
```

Is there any way I can pass the authentication header while spawning Chromium-browser?

Comment: What kind of auth token and what are you trying to do after passing auth token to Chromium?

Comment: Authorization header and Bearer token, and after passing these token i want url to be loaded and it should not be redirected to login page